# Focus events of textfield in sencha touch fires autmatically

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, textfield

I have created an application in Sencha Touch Cordova . In Windows platform when I scroll the panel/container the focus events of a text field fires automatically.
Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please, provide some of your code that could help others to understand your problem better.

Comment: thanks for reply @eyp ..  here is link to code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747587/focus-events-of-textfield-in-sencha-touch-corodva-app-fires-autmatically